# Compilation renders my home page content blank

Tags: magento, compilation, magento-1.7

I want to enable Compilation on our Magento website, but when I enable it, I get blank content for my home page. It stops rendering before outputting the menu. Category and product pages seem to be fine.

We use the Mercado theme, and the home page uses a HomepageGrid block which is a CMS page.

Could anybody provide some insight?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is to check your error log. blank page means php error, and your output configured into error log, not screen. possible places to look:  `path_to/magento/var/log/` files `system.log` and `exception.log`. or `/var/log/` and folders `httpd/error_log` etc. looks like you have some module like featured products or other custom stuff on front page, check your CMS > Pages > Homepage content. thank you